# How can I show only HTML div or td elements ID'ed from a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a randomized sidebar for my website. I have div and tr elements which are ads for my other products, I want to show these randomly on the sidebar of my pages. I want to take these from a different html page because there are about a hundred of them and only 4 or 5 need to be loaded at any one time. I know how to randomize the linking of them, however I do not know enough JavaScript to know how to make **only** the element ID'ed show up. Is this possible to accomplish in JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your sidebar is `#sidebar` and you wish to target a particular ad from an external page (but on the same domain):

```
var adNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // [1, 100]
$('#sidebar').load('/path/to/ads.html #ad' + adNumber);
```

The extra `#ad...` is used by jQuery to load only that selector from the referenced page.

Comment: Ah this is a better approach.